# How does selective packing of external data work?

Tags: packed-data

I would like to pack specific external data into a .blend file.

The Documentation says:

> A single file can be packed by clicking on the little “gift box” icon to the left of its file-path UI widget.
> (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/blend/packed_data.html)

Somehow I am unable to find this “gift box” icon. In which window can I find this “gift box” icon, for example, if I want to pack a font into the blend file?

I know how to pack all external data, but that is not what I want.

Comment: As far as I know, you can only pack images into the file. For other data place all of the data  and the blend file in the same folder and compress the folder as a zip file. Make sure that the links to the data are set to use relative paths.

Comment: @susu You can certainly pack data other then images if you use the "pack all"  function, but maybe you are right and selective packing is only supported for images. Thanks for the suggested workaround.